# How to make two lines text inside list-item element of bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For example I'd like to make a list like in a image attached below. Picture from the left, text with multiple rows in the center, and from the right arrow to navigate to item associated with this item.

The only idea how to achieve such design I have is by using `<table>`, but I know that it's wrong. I've tried to use grid layout of Bootstrap, but it doesn't work inside `list-item` element. Does Bootstrap has helper css classes to achieve this or I need to invite wheel from the beginning?

[image]

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with [`Bootstrap Media Object`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media). Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PP0CC9S9oS1KHPOJdUZD) for you. I haven't styled to look exactly the same, but just to give you idea how to generate this.